# Fastlane is getting provisioning profiles with wrong account

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, fastlane

This is my output on console:

```
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|                      Summary for cert 2.96.1                      |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| development   | false                                             |
| force         | false                                             |
| username      | correctappleid@gmail.com                                |
| team_id       | CSCORRECTTEAMID                                        |
| keychain_path | /Users/bartek/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db |
| platform      | ios                                               |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+

[09:01:23]: Starting login with user 'correctappleid@gmail.com'
[09:01:27]: Successfully logged in
[09:01:28]: Certificate 98TLCZS7BR (iOS Distribution) can't be found on your local computer
[09:01:29]: Found the certificate 6K5C2MFHUL (iOS Distribution) which is installed on the local machine. Using this one.
[09:01:30]: Verifying the certificate is properly installed locally...
[09:01:30]: Successfully installed certificate 6K5C2MFHUL
[09:01:30]: Use signing certificate '6K5C2MFHUL' from now on!
[09:01:30]: --------------------------------------
[09:01:30]: --- Step: get_provisioning_profile ---
[09:01:30]: --------------------------------------

+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
|                             Summary for sigh 2.96.1                             |
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| adhoc                               | false                                     |
| development                         | false                                     |
| skip_install                        | false                                     |
| force                               | false                                     |
| app_identifier                      | my.app.identifier |
| username                            | wrongname@company.com                         |
| team_id                             | CSTEAMID                                |
| ignore_profiles_with_different_name | false                                     |
| cert_id                             | 6K5C2MFHUL                                |
| skip_fetch_profiles                 | false                                     |
| skip_certificate_verification       | false                                     |
| platform                            | ios                                       |
| readonly                            | false                                     |
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+

[09:01:30]: Starting login with user 'wrongname@company.com'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Please provide your Apple Developer Program account credentials
The login information you enter will be stored in your macOS Keychain
You can also pass the password using the `FASTLANE_PASSWORD` environment variable
See more information about it on GitHub: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/credentials_manager
```

> Why fastlane try to fetch provisionings with wrong user account?
>   How can I force it to change it?
>   Where it is defined?

Comment: Is the my.app.identifier app ID associated with the wrongname@company.com account?

Comment: What is the  your fastlane file looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the user account directly?

https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_app_store/#parameters

https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/sigh/#parameters